# Flexslider control nav displaying below than normal CSS instructions just in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, flexslider

I'm using [Flexslider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/) to create some galleries, and I'm styling the `flex-control-nav`, but I realized that is displaying below than normal just in Safari:

[image]

I see this happens in all the sites I used Flexslider, but didn't notice it until now, because in this particular case I need the "perfect" alignment.

Here is my CSS to style the `flex-control-nav`:

```
.mariano-galeria .flex-control-paging li a {
    width: 30px;
    height: 6px;
    background: #666;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 0px;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
}

.mariano-galeria .flex-control-nav {
    height: 6px;
    max-width: 100%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    bottom: 4px;
}
```

Any idea how to fix this alignment in Safari? In all other browsers it's ok.

You can see my [live demo here](http://www.deliciosamentesexy.com/mariano/inicio/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
.mariano-galeria .flex-control-nav {
    bottom: 4px;
    height: 6px;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    right: 0;
}
```

To

```
.mariano-galeria .flex-control-nav {
    height: 6px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative; /* Do not need "position:absolute;" since you are not positioning the navigation on top of the slider */
    line-height: 0; /* it seams Safari was adding extra line-height space */
}
```

**JMarqz Comment:** The real trick here is the **`line-height: 0`**. And make sense, because Flexslider has numbers inside the `flex-control-nav` links and "disappear it" with `text-indent: -9999px`.

**SCREENSHOTS**

Safari:
[image]

---

Firefox:
[image]

---

Internet Explorer 11:
[image]

Comment: Actually I just need the `line-height: 0px`... The use of `line-height` make sense because the `control-nav` in Flexslider have numbers inside de links and "disappear it" with a `text-indent: -9999px`. Thanks a lot for your help, your solution works! I think Flexslider should fix this little thing.

Comment: About the `position: absolute` you're right, but is the "default" behavior of Flexslider, and `position: relative` will change my value of the `bottom`.